# Loop incrementing based on inputs displaying updated value using python

Tags: python, gpio

so what I am having trouble with is, when i hit the button the information overlaps  each other, so I triedadded the write text into the if blocks but it still over laps how do I clear it or just a static number that increases i also need to have a 24 hour timer here that updates siteDay and companyDay by 1 every 24 hrs

```
while True:
    try:
        if(GPIO.input(17)== 1): #alstom increment
            companyDay +=1
            company +=difference1
            turtle.pencolor("orange")
            writeTexts (companyDay, -350,50)
            turtle.pencolor("black")
            writeTexts (company ,-150,-215)
        if(GPIO.input(18)== 1): #alstom decrement
            companyDay -=1
            company -=difference1
             turtle.pencolor("orange")
            writeTexts (companyDay, -350,50)
            turtle.pencolor("black")
            writeTexts (company ,-150,-215)
        if(GPIO.input(27)== 1): #alstom reset
           companyDate == 0
           company ==0
           turtle.pencolor("orange")
            writeTexts(companyDate ,-350,50)
            writeTexts(company ,-150,-215)     
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    writeTexts (site ,500,-215)
    writeTexts (company ,-150,-215)
    writeTexts (today ,500,-310)
    turtle.pencolor("orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all three if statements being only if statements try elif

```
if(condition):
    ...
elif(condition):
   ...
elif(condition):
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Tell me if it works!